# Disable IPV6 using Azure policy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-policy

I would like to disable IPV6 related to all the resources below using custom policy, can you help me the same

disable IPv6 for Azure VNet peering,

DisablePrivateIPv6,

disable IPv6 at Network,

disable IPv6 at Compute<

I tried below one of , but it did n't help

{
"mode": "Indexed",

```
"policyRule": {

    "if": {

        "allOf": [

           {
            "field": "type",

            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
          },

          {
            "not": {

                
              "field":"Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/enableIPV6",
                "equals": false
            }
         }
    ]
},
"then": {
    "effect": "deny"
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to switch from

"mode": "Indexed"

to

`"mode": "All",`

```
{
"mode": "All",
"policyRule": {
    "if": {
        "allOf": [
            {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
            },
            {
                "not": {
                             "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipConfigurations.properties.enableIPv6",
                    "equals": false
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
    }
}
```

}

And use Powershell to apply it

> New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name "myCustomeDisablePolicyIPV6"
> -PolicyDefinition "policy-definition-id" -Scope "scope"

Comment: I tried it in Azure console, I'm still getting an error.